# data url (RFC 2397) の文字列を ruby でパースするには?

Tags: ruby

今、 api サーバーの開発をしている中で、 data url (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) 形式の文字列をパースしてファイル形式に変換して保存する必要が発生しました。

これは、規格としては https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397 で定義されているフォーマットの様子です。規格が定義済みであるならば、おそらく、決まりきったパーサーライブラリなどがあるのではないか、と思っています。

## 質問

- ruby で data url をパースする際のベストプラクティス的なメソッドないしライブラリはありますか?

Comment: "あるのではないか、と思っています" と書かれていますが、実際「あるのか」は下調べなさいましたか？

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が。[Data URI形式の画像をS3へ保存してURLを取得する](https://fintan.jp/?p=3565)

Comment: ベストプラクティスかどうかは知りませんが、 https://rubygems.org/gems/data_uri というのがgemに登録されています。目的の物に合っているかどうかは自分で確認してみてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@らっしー さんから紹介された、 [`data_uri` の gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/data_uri) が、自分の欲しかったライブラリの様子です。

以下利用方法の抜粋:

```
require 'data_uri'

uri = URI::Data.new('data:image/gif;base64,...')
uri.content_type # image/gif
uri.data # Base64 decoded data
```